# Apache curator latencies high for distributed lock

Tags: locking, apache-zookeeper, distributed-system, apache-curator

We have a requirement of distributed locking. The use case is upon acquiring lock it will do a data store read, then update and then write it back to the data store and then release the lock. Our volumes are in the range of 4000 such operations per second. We went with apache curator(5.0.0) for this use case so that we can run multiple instances of our application. Our read update writes will take around 5ms. We started using InterProcessMutex of apache curator for this purpose.

Now we started doing load test with 3 zk servers(4 core, 8GB instances, 3.6.0). zk config as follows

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=/disk1
dataLogDir=/disk3
clientPort=2181
maxClientCnxns=60
server.1=10.11.40.99:2888:3888
server.2=10.11.40.120:2888:3888
server.3=10.11.40.121:2888:3888
metricsProvider.className=org.apache.zookeeper.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusMetricsProvider
metricsProvider.httpPort=7000
metricsProvider.exportJvmInfo=true
autopurge.snapRetainCount=3
autopurge.purgeInterval=1
4lw.commands.whitelist=*
znode.container.maxPerMinute=1000000
skipACL=true
globalOutstandingLimit=1000000
maxClientCnxns=0
```

Some of the java properties we set as follows

```
"-Dznode.container.maxPerMinute=1000000" 
"-Djute.maxbuffer=100000000" 
"-Dznode.container.maxNeverUsedIntervalMs=10000" 
"-Dzookeeper.commitProcessor.maxCommitBatchSize=4" 
"-Dzookeeper.commitProcessor.numWorkerThreads=8" 
"-Dzookeeper.commitProcessor.maxReadBatchSize=8"  
"-Dzookeeper.nio.numWorkerThreads=16"
```

Whatever load we are producing, by tuning parameters multiple times, we never crossed 2000 operations per second(with 2 applications running). lock acquire itself is taking around 30ms on an average and release is taking around 10ms average.

Comment: InterProcessMutex was designed for correctness not necessarily high throughput. Maybe you can consider a different recipe or hand-coding something for this use case. If you detail your use-case it might be easier to suggest an alternative.

Comment: @Randgalt, thanks for the reply but figured out the issue. The throughput issue is because of enabling Prometheus provider which scraps zookeeper for every 10 seconds. Disabled it and we can process around 5500 operations per second.